# importxml formula in Google Sheets adds random cell below it

Tags: xml, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, bitcoin

I want to fetch the bitcoin price through the formula importxml, which it works.

The problem is that it adds a random value to the cell below it. I can't delete it.

This is the formula

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"&D1, "//div[contains(@class, 'priceValue')]")
```

This is the result (what's that number (0.0668) there?):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"&D1,"//div[@class='priceValue ']")
```

[image]

Comment: It worked with your previous suggestion, and this one as well.
I am really curious to understand why that extra space at the end changes this. Thanks!

Comment: this should clear up the confusion (https://i.imgur.com/7rXOlOI.png)